# How to measure uptime between restarts

Tags: init.d

I want to track my time at the desk. As a first approximation, I guess tracking the time the computer is turned on, and then subtracting the relatively constant lunch break should do.

How can I execute a script at the early stages of shutting down of my `Debian jessie`?

Comment: uptime between restarts? It's downtime. What do you want to accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[13ushm4n](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/154899/13ushm4n)'s answer shows how to execute a script during shutdown, but if you want to track the amount of time your computer is on, there are tools for that. On Debian, you could use [`uptimed`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/uptimed); it will automatically keep track of the total amount of time your computer is on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Make a script in /etc/init.d/ (make sure that it is executable - `chmod ugo+x /etc/rc0.d/S##your_script` and make a symbolic link in /etc/rc0.d/ - `ln -s /etc/rc0.d/S##your_script /etc/rc0.d/S##your_script_symbolic_link` ).

rc0.d is shutdown, if you want restarts too then make the symling in rc6.d as well.